# Oracle UCM - Where is the Workflow Content Action History log kept

Tags: oracle, workflow, logging, history, content-management

After a workflow has completed, I would like to be able to review a documents "Workflow Content Action History", just as you would see on the "Workflow Info" page. Currently when a document is in workflow you have access to this page but after the workflow completes you do not? Where does the UCM store this info and how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

The workflow history is stored in the WORKFLOWHISTORY database table and the table can be queried by installing the following component:

http://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/document_and_workflow_history